# Gif image not displayed on html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gif, animated-gif

I have a html page and whilst it's waiting for data from the server it should display an animated `gif` image to show that it is waiting.

This is the code:

```
 $("#display").append('<img src="/templates/image.gif alt="red" width="30" height="30" " />');
```

This is the html:

```
 <div style="margin:0 auto;" id="display"></div>
```

The animated gif was taken from the gif generator at : http://www.ajaxload.info/ and put into the relevant directory.

But instead all that is displayed is a 'broken picture icon' in Google chrome and nothing is displayed at all in Firefox. It seems like it cannot access the `.gif file` as I get a `404 error` when I try and access the file from the server. Eventhough I can see it in the directory in my workspace.

I cannot see what the problem might me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox hides 'broken images' and Chrome/internet explorer show a broken image placeholder.

Seems like you didnt close the src attribute.

```
$("#display").append('<img src="/templates/image.gif alt="red" width="30" height="30" " />');
```

should be

```
$("#display").append('<img src="/templates/image.gif" alt="red" width="30" height="30" />');
```

Comment: Thanks...It wasn't that though. Seems like it cannot find the file as I get a 404 error. But I can see the file in the right directory in my workspace.

Comment: Oh, then it's just a matter of 'trying' directories. You can use '../' to go a dir higher. How does your workspace look like?

Comment: What you can do, is place the full URL in a variable. Like:
var siteurl = 'http://www.google.nl';
And use it like this in your img src:
$("#display").append('<img src="' + siteurl + '/templates/image.gif" alt="red" width="30" height="30" />');.
That way, you know exactly where to find it.

Comment: I tried that, still the same error. But when I try to access the file from my browser then the gif image appears fine!

Comment: What happens when you add the URL from your browser into the <img src="" ?

Comment: Ok got it now. I deleted most of the infor= in the `src tag` to just: ` $("#display").append('<img src= "/static/image.gif" />');`

Comment: Ah, glad you figured it out and no problem :)